# Transition Between Curve Types Using D3.js

Tags: d3.js

I'd like to transition between curve types using D3.js.

Take a look at [this block](https://bl.ocks.org/iaindillingham/67835c954c5e3a1fd00eed35a0b37765). The data stay the same but the curve type changes. I was expecting the paths to maintain their approximate positions on the plane -- the data stay the same, after all -- but they don't. The paths appear to be redrawn, although I don't understand why with basis to linear the paths seem to be redrawn from left to right whilst with linear to basis the paths seem to be redrawn from right to left.

I've read Mike Bostock's post on [Path Transitions](https://bost.ocks.org/mike/path/), but I think this is a slightly different problem. There, the data change but the curve type remains the same. Here, the data stay the same but the curve type changes.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 2):

To understand why you have such a *strange* transition, let's compare the `d` attribute of the paths using a `curveBasis` and a `curveLinear`.

First, a `curveBasis`:

> d="M0,101.2061594964L45.48756294826797,89.52282837400001C90.97512589653594,77.83949725160001,181.95025179307189,54.47283500680002,271.46268884480395,84.08731623460001C360.975125896536,113.70179746240001,449.0248741034641,196.2974221628,538.5373111551961,222.09899531679994C628.0497482069281,247.90056847079998,719.0248741034642,216.90809007840002,764.512437051732,201.4118508822L810,185.915611686"

Now a `curveLinear` (same data):

> d="M0,101.2061594964L272.92537768960784,31.10617276200003L537.0746223103922,278.89304686319997L810,185.915611686"

As you can see, the path is way simpler with `curveLinear`. So, the strange transition is the expected behaviour.

A possible solution is using a path interpolation, as proposed in [this code](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3916621) from Mike Bostock.

Here is your bl.ocks with a path interpolation: http://blockbuilder.org/anonymous/02125b1fb145a979e53f369c4976a772

PS: If you want to avoid that strange transition when you load the page (all paths coming from the top left corner), draw them the first time using a regular `attr` method.

Comment: It might be worth being a bit more precise: the behaviour is caused by the (implicit) use of the string interpolator [`d3.interpolateString(a, b)`](https://github.com/d3/d3-interpolate#interpolateString) which finds numbers in the strings and interpolates from the *n*th position in string `a` to the *n*th position in string `b`, leaving the remainder of `b`untouched in case no more corresponding number is found. Thus, as you already noted, a mismatch in the count of numbers in both strings, will result in the observed behaviour.

Comment: Thank you. The short answer, as you suggest, is that a custom interpolator is required for SVG path elements. The link to Mike Bostock's Path Tween block is really useful for a longer answer. I think @altocumulus is right though -- it's useful to know about the implicit use of the string interpolator.